# Rails 3.2: Failed Assertion uniqueness: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

All,

I am having trouble with testing a model,  I have a simple customer table that uses the following fields:  name:string, location:string, full_name:string, active:boolean.   I am using the full_name field as a hidden field that contains the following "#{name} #{location}" and testing the record for uniqueness on the full_name field.

The test "customer is not valid without a unique full_name" is that test that I am having an issue with, I am trying to test an insertion of a duplicate record.  If I remove the bang(!) in front of assert !customer.save the test will pass.  this is acting like the fixtures are not being loaded into the table prior to running the test,I am running rake test:units.  I have tried running the server in development mode and inserted two records using the scaffolding and the second insertion fails and reports an error "Full name has already been taken" which is the expected behavior.

can anyone give me some guidance on where I have screwed up the test!

Thanks in advance

Reback

---

Model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :full_name, :location, :name

  validates :active, :location, :name, presence: true
  validates :full_name, uniqueness: true              # case I am trying to test

  before_validation :build_full_name

  def build_full_name
    self.full_name = "#{name} #{location}"
  end

end
```

---

Test Fixture customers.yml

```
one:
  name: MyString
  location: MyString
  full_name: MyString
  active: false

two:
  name: MyString
  location: MyString
  full_name: MyString
  active: false

general:
  name: 'Whoever'
  location: 'Any Where'
  full_name: ''
  active: true
```

---

Test Unit Helpers customer_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class CustomerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true 
  # end

  fixtures :customers

  # Test fields have to be present
  test "customer fields must not be empty" do
    customer = Customer.new
    assert customer.invalid?
    assert customer.errors[:name].any?
    assert customer.errors[:location].any?
    assert_equal " ", customer.full_name     # This is processed by a helper function in the model
    assert customer.errors[:active].any?
  end

  # Test full_name field is unique
  test "customer is not valid without a unique full_name" do
    customer = Customer.new(
    name: customers(:general).name,
    location: customers(:general).location,
    full_name: customers(:general).full_name,
    active: customers(:general).active
    )

    assert !customer.save   # this is the line that fails
    assert_equal "has already been taken", customer.errors[:full_name].join(', ')
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the fixture customers.yml:

I assumed that the fixture would be processed through the model and that the build_full_name helper would be called before the data was inserted into the test database.  That does not seem to be the case.

I changed the fixture as follows and it corrected the problem:

```
one:
 name: MyString
 location: MyString
 full_name: MyString
 active: false

two:
 name: MyString2         # changed for consistency, was not the problem
 location: MyString2
 full_name: MyString2
 active: false

general:
 name: 'Whoever'
 location: 'Any Where'
 full_name: 'Whoever Any Where'  #Here was the problem
 active: true
```